Why is React not rerendering with infinite scroll component?
export default function Foo() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
    function fetchData() {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:4000/api/getcontent?page=" + page)
          .then((res) => {
            setPage(page + 1)
            setItems((items) => [...items, ...res.data])
          }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    function refresh() {
        setPage(0)
        setItems([])
    }


    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
        next={fetchData}
        refreshFunction={refresh}
        pullDownToRefresh
        pullDownToRefreshThreshold={50}
        pullDownToRefreshContent={
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8595; Pull down to refresh</h3>
        }
        releaseToRefreshContent={
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8593; Release to refresh</h3>
        }>

        </InfiniteScroll>
    );
};

I got an infinite scroll component that, upon refresh will call the "refresh" function. This refresh function currently simply sets the page number. It does not work. The page will be stuck at loading. However, if I replace the refresh function with a copy of fetchData, then everything works just fine. Why is this?
